# Search Excel from Html page formula

Tags: html, excel

I am currently working on a project and the end goal is for someone to put in the part specification and then the part number and data comes out. I need help to get my html page to search my excel  spreadsheet with the specifications and then spit out the part number and price and data. Here's where my inspiration is coming from http://www.lesker.com/newweb/flanges/nipple_builder.cfm
If anyone can help me with a code to search my spreadsheet I would greatly appreciate it, I'm a bit of a novice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need a dynamic approach to handle this goal. You can not get HTML to Excel work together and the best alternative is to use PHP+MySQL, upload your database to your web server and query it using php. You will have great difficulties if you use only HTML when it comes to update your items in the list.

Comment: Thank You so much, I have started using MySQL and so far so good, thanks for the help.